# Target current menu item in a single page site with fixed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I'm working a single-page website for my friend's photo studio: http://dev.manifold.ws/yorckstudio/
The site is divided in six sections, each the size of the viewport. When you click on one of the menu item, it takes you to the corresponding section. What I can't figure out is how to get a menu item to be underline when viewing the corresponding section. So if I'm viewing the "Photos" section, the item "Photos" in my fixed menu would be underlined.

My guess is that there must be a relatively simple way to achieve that with a bit of javascript / jQuery magic. But my js skills being quite poor, I'm not sure where to start.

Does anyone have a idea of how this could be achieved?

Cheers,

Thom

Comment: This sounds like a good use for [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, add this is your JS:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
  $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').css('text-decoration','none');
})
```

This will add an underline to the clicked anchor tags and remove the attribute on all the other ones.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z97RX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#menu ul li a').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.addClass('underline');
    that.parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('underline');
});
```

And add to css

```
.underline{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could, please take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/xv8tf/3/

It could be cleaned up a bit, but here is the jist of it.

All you require to do on your end is update you menu and your scrollto elements and just add a rel tag with matching values

Example:

> ```
> <div id="menu">
>     <ul>
>         <li><a rel="photos" href="javascript:void(0)">Photos</a></li>
>
>     </ul>
> </div>
>
> <div rel="photos" id="photos"></div>
> ```

```
//create a list of all elements to be tested against
var scrollMatches = [
    $('#photos'),
    $('#studio'),
    $('#rates'),
    $('#features'),
    $('#plan'),
    $('#contact')
];

$(window)
.on('scroll', function(){
    //save scrolltop to var to prevent multiple callings
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    //iterate through each of the elements to be testing against
    $.each(scrollMatches, function(k, v){
        var offset = v.offset()

        // if the element is in the viewport
        if(offset.top  <= scroll && (offset.top + v.outerHeight()) > scroll){
            // get associated element
            var element = $('#menu li > a[rel='+v.attr('rel')+']');

            // do whatever you want to the current tested element
            element.css('text-decoration','underline');

            // dp whatever you want to the associated menu item
            element.parent().siblings().find('a').css('text-decoration','none');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```